# How to hide show recyclerView from SearchView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, searchview

I have a a recyclerView which shows a list of item . What i am trying to acheive is when i type a word the recyclerView should disappear and when there is no text then recyclerView should reappear. The problem is recyclerView hides successfully but it does not reappear when i clear the text from the searchView.

> Here is the code snippet of callback function

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    if(newText.length()==0)
    {
        historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // musicAdapter.filter(newText);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `else` statement?

Comment: Haha.. You missed `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if(newText == null || newText.length()){
    historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
if(nextText.isEmpty)
  {
  historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
historyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```